# Hidden $RECYCLE.BIN folder taking up 30GB in brand new drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, recycle-bin

I've just recently acquired a 1TB disk, and installed it on my computer. It barely has any files on it (specifically, only a 3KB password file), but Windows Explorer says it has 35GB in use.

[image: 35.8GB / 895GB]

As you can see, there is a lot of space in use. However, when browsing the contents of the drive, there is nothing notably large to see. (Show Hidden Files is enabled, by the way)

[image: Lonely 3KB file]

This seems very strange for a new drive. Maybe it's something related to caching? My computer surely does have more than enough RAM for operating.

**EDIT:** Following the answer in @ChrisInEdmonton's dupe hint, I discovered that there is a 30GB $RECYCLE.BIN folder taking up 30GB, in addition to the System Volume Information folder, with 5GB in it. Is it safe to remove this folder?

Comment: This a used driver or something?

Comment: @Ramhound Nope, brand new. Just bought, plugged and formatted it.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton Indeed it seems like a possible reason, however according to `vssadmin list shadowstorage`, the System Restore Service appears to only use about 5GB. Following that answer I found out that there is a $RECYCLE.BIN folder using the remaining 30GB. Is it safe to remove this folder?

Comment: I would re-adjust your recycle bin settings for starters windows likes using the largest disk for stuff like this